# Newly created Azure Web App with Overview and Activity Log not found?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

I created a brand new web app on Azure. However, on navigating to the web app's page, the blades (panels) showcasing the service's overview and activity log (titled "Overview" and "Activity Log" respectively) is unavailable.

A simple error page indicating it is not found is displayed instead. I have attempted to tinker with the two suggestions on the page regarding publish profiles (get and reset options) but to no avail.

I doubt there is an issue with my deployment method as I chose all the default values during setup.
What could be the issue?

[Here is an image of the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF40m.png)
Please note, I am still unable to post images in the questions. 
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please clean sessions and cookies then try again. Or try to use other computer to see whether it is your environment issue.

> I doubt there is an issue with my deployment

Is this issue caused by your Azure subscription? If you create a new Azure web app, could you see the below screenshot? 
[image]
If it is not your Azure subscription issue, please provide more details for us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Sessions and cookies were cleared and my Azure subscription is yet to expire. And yes, accessing the URL results in the screen shot above. Still cannot access numerous options from the main page of the Web App.

Comment: I think it is not a coding or deployment issue. I would suggest you contact with Azure support to fix this type issue. Refer to this article for more information about creating azure support request: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/how-to-create-azure-support-request/

Comment: Sadly, submitting a support request requires subscribing to a support plan. I am but a student. Microsoft recommends posting on StackOverflow or MSDN for problem resolution. Tried both. Using the old portal should resolve the issues but the fix is only temporary and I need to integrate a function app (also giving me the same problems and not available on the old portal) with my project. Thank you for your help!